# UK visit visa refused under alleged deception?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, deception

I was recently refused a standard 6-month UK visit visa. I'm not here to prove myself, it is totally a mistake the HO has made here and I need to find a way to resolve this farce.

My very first application and refusal in 2019 was on the basis that I did not have sufficient funds, and the ECO did not think my intentions were that of what I stated. There was no confirmation of alleged deception on that specific application or notifying of a 10-year travel ban. Now fast-forward 4 years, my circumstances have changed and I'm in a much better position financially, so I decided to accept an invitation from my sibling (UK resident) this year and spend the new year in the UK with his family.

The HO has only stated records show deception in a previous application was used and stated a ban until 2029, which is ludicrous.

This is 100% a mistake and I need this overturned, but I have been told there's no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

The HO has not even given the reason to the alleged deception, which baffles me.

My question is, do I apply again for them to automatically refuse me due to the aforementioned, or is there a specific team within the entry clearance team to contact and request a detailed report as to how they arrived at that ludicrous decision?

This is a very sensitive issue and I would appreciate some good advice on the matter. TIA.

**This is the 2019 letter:**

[image: 2019 Refusal_1]

[image: 2019 Refusal]

**This is the 2023 letter:**

[image: 2023 Refusal]

Comment: What was the date of the first refusal? Are you sure you didn’t submit another application after that, either directly or indirectly through some kind of agency for instance?

Comment: @jcaron First ever application to the UK was in 05/2019 which was refused and not applied till this year.

Comment: Get the advice of a registered sollicitor, this is bad @Box562

Comment: You applied in May 2019 and received your refusal in December?

Comment: @phoog please read the question properly and accompanying refusal letters. First ever UK visa Application was in 2019 and most recent in 2023.

Comment: It's not clear that the first letter shown is 2019.

Comment: It's interesting that the unconvincing 2019 application where the officer was "not satisfied with your intensions *[sic]*" was later turned into "breached immigration laws" and "deception".

Comment: @Weather Vane please read the question with the accompanying photos which I've updated clearly shows refusal in 2019 and since not applied until 2023.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't originally. Please excuse me for trying to make it even more clear with another edit which separates the letters.

Comment: Interestingly, the refusal letter from 2019 is full of typos and bizarre grammar. I'm wondering if it has been doctored in some ways. Did you submit your 2019 application yourself directly to a UKVI office, or via some kind of intermediary?

Comment: ... and was the latest one submitted through an agent?

Comment: I am also suspicious of the letter.  I guess that it is possible that someone in the Home Office writes that poorly but I hope not.  Is it possible that you have been scammed by an agent?  Maybe they took a fee from you but never submitted anything and gave you a fake rejection letter.

Comment: Both applications submitted in person and both refusals received via email.

Comment: I shall be proceeding with a SAR and will be instructing a UK solicitor. Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: The first letter looks like it was written by someone who copy pasted parts of an original letter, and ad-libbed, decorating the letter with typos, random capitals, commas, and, generally, a shaky grasp of English grammar. From the currency mentioned I gather you're from Ghana, but the letter looks like it was produced by an Indian. Very strange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an odd situation. Your May 2019 refusal letter should state any finding of deception, if there was indeed one. Both letters have quite a few typos. If you have applied via an agent, I'd consider it plausible that the letters are fake.

Your first action could be to file a subject access request with the home office:
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

That way you would learn what information they actually have about you. If the second visa application never actually reached them, you can then apply for real. If the subject access request does not clarify the situation, you may have to instruct an immigration lawyer. They should be endorsed by the UK Law Society (https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/?Pro=True).

Comment: I have put in a (SAR) and received a response from the unit requesting personal details will keep everyone posted on the outcome.